# Aller ou venir chez quelqu'un ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Laquelle de ces deux phrases est juste

1. J'aimerais aller chez toi.
2. J'aimerais venir chez toi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Les deux sont justes et utilisées, chacune dans un contexte différent :

Aller est utilisé si la personne B n'est pas chez elle et A veut aller chez B.

Venir est utilisé si la personne B est chez elle et A demande à rejoindre B.